# Xamarin Forms Hide TabbedPage in Details Page But Keep Back Button

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a xamarin forms TabbedPage page with a listview on the first page. When i click the listview, i want to be able to hide the tabs (because the listview Item takes the user to a page that displays details about that item. This is the reason i only want the user to be able to press the back button to get back to the TabbedPage)... How do I accomplish this?

So Far, the closest i have got to it was to re-assigning **App.Current.MainPage**

```
ListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
 App.Current.MainPage= new NavigationPage(new MyNewPage());
}
```

However, i lose my back button...How do i make the details page, hide tabs in details page, and not lose my back button? (It seems so commonly done in most popular android apps)

The best example to describe what i am trying to do is in Delta's "Fly Delta" android app.. On the main screen, there is a TabbedPage. When I click "Recent Activity" , I am sent to a details page with no Tabs, but the details page has a back button. When i click the Back Button, it sends me back to the TabbedPage.

[TabbedPage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDcou.png)

[Details Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP39t.png)

Comment: Don't switch main page. Make main page to be navigation page and add your tabbed page inside main page

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a Custom Renderer of your `TabbedPage` something like:

```
public class CustomTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
        public static readonly BindableProperty TabBarHiddenProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("TabBarHidden", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomTabbedPage), false);

        public bool TabBarHidden
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(TabBarHiddenProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TabBarHiddenProperty, value); }
        }
}

using System;
using yourAppName;
using yourAppName.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomTabbedPage), typeof(CustomTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace yourAppName.iOS
{
    public class CustomTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            this.Tabbed.PropertyChanging += (sender, eventArgs) => {
                if (eventArgs.PropertyName == "TabBarHidden" && TabBar.SelectedItem == TabBar.Items[3])
                {
                    bool tabBarHidden = !tmp.TabBarHidden;
                    TabBar.Hidden = tabBarHidden;
                    Console.WriteLine(View.Frame.Width + " " + View.Frame.Height);

                // The solution to the space left behind the invisible tab bar
                    if(TabBar.Hidden)
                        View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 0);
                    else
                        View.Subviews[1].Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(View.Subviews[1].Frame.X, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Y, View.Subviews[1].Frame.Width, 49);

                }
            };


        }
    }
}
```

For Android I am using this: https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF